# AWS S3 Slow Download

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I do have a problem in AWS S3. I put a big file size in the S3 Storage and copied the download link to my website. But the problem is when I tried to click the download link and start the download progress. The Download speed is super slow and sometimes it stuck to 0kbps even my internet connection is fast. Is there any tips to increase the download speed of my big file size from AWS S3?

**EDIT:**

1. File size: 60 MB
2. Server location: asia-pacific(Singapore)
3. Caching: No
4. Access location: Philippines

Comment: 1. What's the size? 2. Where is the server location? 3. Is file on a cache server? 4. Where are you trying to download from(your location)?

Comment: @mnmopazem 1. 60mb size. 2. asia-pacific(Singapore). 3. No. 4. From Philippines

Comment: Did you try a full download? If so, how much time did it take?

Comment: yes, I full download the file and it takes 35min to 1hour with 20- 60kbps.

Comment: Sometimes when I redownload again the file the download speed is increased. It takes 200kbps or more.

Comment: I suggest you upload it to different(try atleast with 3) servers(like Google docs) and download same. While downloading: 1. try with same time of the day for each download 2. try not to do other Internet activities and 3. make sure your bandwidth is same as when you downloaded from AWS server. Note the time and compare it with AWS download time. This could give you some comparision to make. As an alternative, explore AWS caching options.

Comment: Preferably, try to upload and download from sites/servers located in Singapore.